# iPhone Settings.bundle - how to disable/enable a setting based on other settings?

Tags: iphone, settings, appsettings, application-settings

Hard to explain, but luckily there's an example.  On an iPhone, when you go to Settings > Nike + iPod, in the app's settings, when you set Nike+iPod to off, it disables the rest of the settings. How do I do that?  Use one setting to disable or toggle off another setting?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325188/5702544)

Comment: Please take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325188/5702544)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For AppStore apps, no you can't do that, period.

---

Detail: Nike+iPod is using a different mechanism known as "Preferences Bundle", which allows more kinds of specifiers (e.g. buttons) and running code. To disable settings live, one need codes. "Settings Bundle" which AppStore allows cannot run code. So that cannot be done.